# How can I get the type information at point?

Tags: scala, emacs, language-server-protocol, scala-metals

When I put my cursor within a function that as additional function calls. The status bar appears to only show the type information for the outer most variable. [image: attached image]
I see the type for `clientFutureBackend` whereas I'd expect to see type info for `SttpBackendOptions.connectionTimeout(10.seconds)`

Is there a way to get more pinpoint type information?

Comment: Brute force, but making it `SttpBackendOptions.connectionTimeout(10.seconds) : Nothing)` will get you a compiler error of the "found: [actual type] expected: Nothing" variety.

Comment: My goal is to replace IntelliJ though so having to go through extra effort wouldn't be worth unfortunately